# Calculate future date using interval (in number of weeks) and a starting date

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to write a function to calculate the next date that a piece of equipment needs to be checked. I'm using the code below (it's incomplete.)

```
function get_next_check(){

    $today = date(get_option('date_format'));

    $first_check = types_get_field_meta_value( 'first_check', $post_id );

    // Interval is a number of weeks- ie. month = 4, year = 52
    $interval = types_get_field_meta_value( 'interval', $post_id );

    // Calculate the next date after today that the check needs to be performed
    $next_check = ;

    return $next_check;

}
add_shortcode( 'next_check', 'get_next_check' );
```

I'm guessing I need to create an array of all possible dates, and compare each to today's date, only returning the next one?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$first_check` is a string with the date in it, and you want the function to return the same, something like this might work:

```
$week = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7; // number of seconds in a week
$next_check = strtotime($first_check);
while ($next_check < time()) {
    $next_check += $week * $interval; // advance the check time by the desired interval
}

return date(get_option('date_format'), $next_check);
```

You can eliminate your initialization of the `$today` variable with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this on the proposed by Greg Schmidt , or alternatively by doing:

```
// Calculate the next date after today that the check needs to be performed
$next_check = date(get_option('date_format'), strtotime($today." ".$interval." weeks"));
```